# Xamarin Forms Switch with Task

Tags: c#, for-loop, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I'm new in programming with Xamarin (actually even with C# tbh)

What I'm trying to acheave is a Task which should only work when a Switch (called S1) is Toggled.

My idea:

```
public async Task GetCon(){
        for (; ; )
        {
            if (S1.IsToggled == true)
            {
                AI1.IsRunning = true;
                bool CStat = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsRemoteReachable("https://www.google.ch");
                if (CStat == true)
                {
                    StatLbl.Text = "Online";
                }
                else if (CStat == false)
                {
                    StatLbl.Text = "Offline";
                    break;
                }
            off:;   
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
```

All works fine but if I turn the Switch back off and make google unreachable, the StatLbl text doesn't change to offline.
Any idea?

Comment: You're changing the UI and all UI changes have to be done on the Main/UIThread, which from your async Task is probably not the case. If you wrap both text changes in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( ()=>StatLbl.Text = "Online");` it will probably start working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're new to C#, I'm surprised no-one else has picked up on this, but here goes.

Instead of infinitely running a `Task` and waiting for the switch to be toggled, use the `Toggled` event to trigger when the toggle status changes. How does it work? When you toggle the switch, your program will automatically call that method. For example:

```cs
public MyConstructor()
{
    S1.Toggled += S1_Toggled;
}

void S1_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Switch is now {0}", e.Value));
}
```

You can find more information (and some example) for the Switch at the [Xamarin Forms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.switch?view=xamarin-forms).

As **Jason** pointed out, you should be modifying UI properties from the UI thread. Properties like colour, visibility, text etc (anything that changes on the display) should be done in `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` like so:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
{
    StatLbl.Text = "Offline";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute UI changes on the UI thread

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  StatLbl.Text = "Offline";
});
```

Comment: There is no indication that this is happening on non-UI thread and there are other problems in the code that would cause the described behavior, look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code executes only when the switch is on, you have this line that prevents from changing the label name when the switch is on:

```
    if (S1.IsToggled == true)
```